# flutter firestore update data method

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update the card data I brought from firestore

when I use onTap in Inkwell I want to change data in this card.

this is my search service. I am using this for bring data from firestore

how can I make update function on this situation. thanks for help

```
class SearchService {
List<Future<QuerySnapshot>> searchByName() {
return [
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('dis')
      .where('no')
      .orderBy('date', descending: true )
      .getDocuments(),
   ];
  }
}
```

this is my Card code

```
Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context , data) {
return Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
  elevation: 5,
  child: ExpansionCard(


    title: Column(
              children: [

                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 1),
                      child: Text(data['isim'],
                        style:  GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontSize: 20 , textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                     InkWell(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.update,
                            color: Colors.white54,
                          ),
                          onTap: (){//I want to set update function here// 
                             },
                    )

                  ],
                ),
             );
           }
```

and this is my adddata function

```
Future<void> addData(carData) async {
if (isLoggedIn()) {
  Firestore.instance.collection('dis').add(carData).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
  });

} else {
  print('You need to be logged in');
}
```

}

a little bit long but this is my addmethod

```
crudMedthods crudObj = new crudMedthods();

  Future<bool> addDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Temsilci Verisi Ekleyin.', style:  GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.black54, 
    fontSize: 22 , textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(

            width: _width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[

                Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      onTap: (){
                        showDatePicker(context: context,
                            initialDate: _dateTime == null ? DateTime.now() : _dateTime,
                            firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2030)).then((date) {
                          setState(() {
                            _dateTime = date;
                          });
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: _dateTime == null ? 'Uygulama Sıralama 
     Takvimi Giriniz' : _dateTime.toString()),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        this._dateTime = value as DateTime;
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),

                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Temsilci'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.temsilci = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextField(

                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Sıra No'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.sirano = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Tarih'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.tarih = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Veri Kaynağı'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.verik = value;
                  },
                ),
               
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Verileri Sisteme Ekleyin'),
            textColor: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              crudObj.addData({
                'date': this._dateTime,

                'no': this.no,
                'temsilci': this.temsilci,
                'sıra no': this.sirano,
                'tarih': this.tarih,
                'veri kaynağı': this.verik,
                

             }).then((result) {
                dialogTrigger(context);
              }).catchError((e) {
                print(e);
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
```

}

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: I dont have update function and I dont know how can I write

Comment: try this, you have to pass the documetID from data properly 
@PeterHaddad correct me if i am wrong in getting the documentID from data , rest should work fine .

`await  Firestore.instance.collection('dis').document(data.documentID).updateData(
  {
    'date': "new data",
    'no': ""new data",
    'temsilci': ""new data",
    'sıra no': "new data",
    'tarih': ""new data"",
    'veri kaynağı': "new data",
  });`